# pop notification when clicked on disable option in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, formgroups

i am trying to pop a notification `(alert)` when i click on disable option.

First i have this component.html:

```
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="from-group">
          <label for="vehicle"> Vehicle </label>
          <select
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="vehicle_index"
            (click)="showAlert()"

           >
           <option value="">--Select a Vehicle--</option>
            <option
              *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles; let i = index"
              value="{{ i }}"
              [disabled]="vehicle.id == 8"
            >
               {{vehicle.model}} - {{vehicle.plate_number}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

As we see i disable from option when `id = 8`.

function `showAlert()` :

```
  showAlert(){
    if (this.plannedRouteForm.get("vehicle_index").value.disabled == true) {
      alert(" Disabled");
  }
  }
```

what i am thinking about is when i click on value in option i check if is disable? then show alert.

But unfortunately `NOT WORK`.

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mat select item disabled can't clicked...

material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Try to add a custom CSS, you can change [disabled] with [class.nameyourclass]="vehicle.id ==8" try to add a background red only for test.

Comment: no, i thing we can pop notification on disabled option when clicked on it, btw how to replicates using css ?
any example? @Den

Comment: Now I can't pass an example... Sorry... When I have time I try to create an example

Comment: I check.... But mat select item disabled can't clicked...https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview ... To add a custom CSS you can change disabled with [class.nameyourclass]="vehicle.id ==8" try to add a background red only for test

Comment: yes that it thank you! , and you right we can't click on disable option.
please put your answer and your suggest to vote it.
@Den